# Solving time for nonlinear problems?

Tags: mathematical-optimization, nonlinear-optimization

I've been working on a large nonlinear program, but I'm running into time issues (the computer will run for 2+ days and not find a solution). The problem requires ~244 variables per day, spread out over ~30 days, for a total of around 7000 variables. It seems like this is a huge number of variables, and when I try to solve the problem it takes an extremely long time.

I'm currently using the Ipopt solver. How long does it usually take to solve nonlinear programs of this size? I've tried googling the answer but large range of answers. I'm currently using a laptop with 4 GB of ram and I'm allocating 3 GB to java to help solve the problem, I'm not sure if memory is an issue or not. The nonlinearity is in the objective function, where I divide a quantity by the objective function (i.e. constant/x).

Something I'm currently trying is to make the decision variables all be greater than or equal to .75, rather than 0, in case the issue involved dividing by zero, although I'm not sure if that will solve the problem, because this is a minimization problem so you wouldn't want to go near zero! Thanks in advance for any help that can be provided!

Comment: "constant/x" - that's all, and no nonlinear constraints? Couldn't you just optimize over x and flip the direction? Am I missing something?

Comment: Try solving a case with 100 variables, one with 200 variables and one with 400 variables. Then you can extrapolate/estimate if 7000 variable will take 3 days or 3 billion years :)

Comment: the constant is a fixed cost that's different for each x. So constant(x)/x would be a better way of describing it. What do you mean by flip the direction?

Comment: I see a lot of NLP models that do not solve (or do not solve fast enough) and many of them much larger than your model. The first thing I do is try a few different solvers (e.g. IPOPT, CONOPT, KNITRO, MINOS, SNOPT).. This is the easiest if you model is stated in a modeling language like AMPL or GAMS. Next, many problems are related to three areas: (1) a poor initial point, (2) poor scaling and (3) poor bounds. If I read your question correctly  you may also try to maximize x instead of minimizing C/x (that could make the model linear so using a linear solver makes sense).

Comment: Also you should check and recheck your gradients (and hessian) if you did not use automatic differentiation.

Comment: @DrFabulous well I thought you had `cont / f(variables)` (a fairly literal interpretation of "constant divided by objective function"), then maximizing that is the same as minimizing f (and vice versa). But apparently you meant the vector, so that doesn't work.

Comment: @Erwin Kalvelagen, the only problem with AMPL and GAMS (minos, knitro, conopt) they are free for relatively small problems and for large-scale ones they are way not cheap, wonderful modeling systems though. It's worth mentioning BARON as state-of-the-art global solver.

Comment: @DrFabulous, did you try to solve equivalent problem or use fractional programming tricks: http://www.seas.ucla.edu/~vandenbe/ee236a/lectures/lfp.pdf ?